# mysql_user issue with priv

Tags: mysql, ansible

In my playbook i have something like:

```
- name: Creates a mysql user
  mysql_user:
    login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
    login_user: "{{ db_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ db_password }}"
    name: my_user
    password: 123123
    state: present
    priv: "*.*:ALL"
```

If i run that, i am getting:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "(1045, \"Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'%' (using password: YES)\")"}

However, if i run it without the priv part:

```
- name: Creates a mysql user
  mysql_user:
    login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
    login_user: "{{ db_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ db_password }}"
    name: my_user
    password: 123123
    state: present
```

The user is created normally. The priv string is an example taken from the docs [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html), so it should work.
I tested with several ansible versions (>1.9.4)

Comment: Does `dbuser` have enough permissions to grant `my_user` privileges to all databases?

Comment: Yeah, was missing "with grant option" on my_user. The error is a little misleading because it looks like an access issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> Does `dbuser` have enough permissions to grant `my_user` privileges to all databases?